# Javascript - do variables with self-updating value exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to create a variable that whenever called will return current value. Example should picture this better:

```
var image = jQuery('.myimage');
var currentWidth = function(){ return image.width(); };
// now, in any later place in the script the above variable
// should contain the current width without necessity to update this
// variable over and over again each time (we assume that the width
// of an image is changing as the script executes and this variable
// should always contain the CURRENT width and not the one set at the
// beginning).
```

So, whenever width changes, I'd like to be able to get the current width. Is something like that possible? The above example returns a string for me and not the current value.

Comment: Is that not the behavior that you're seeing? That's how this code should work. If it isn't, you should post more of the context.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo he wants to be able to refer to "currentWidth" without explicitly making a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a *variable* that, when interrogated in an expression, results in code being evaluated (that is, a function call), but it's possible to define an object property with a getter function that's invoked when the property is accessed.

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "dyn", {
  get: function() {
    return new Date().getTime(); // just an example
  }
});
```

Every time `obj.dyn` is referenced, the value will be the current timestamp.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. So, it's only possible with objects and not single variables that will self-update?

Comment: @Paul that's right, only object properties.  Variables are always just variables with simple values.

Comment: Great :) Perhaps that's even better for code organization. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul note that this is not supported on Internet Explorer 8 and older. (Well IE8 has some semi-working support but only for DOM objects.)

Comment: Fortunately IE8 is almost dead after wasting a billion of hours for developers around the globe :) Finally.

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking you can just do the following:

```
function currentWidth() {
   return $('.myimage').width();   // or image.width() since you have it defined, make sure there is ONLY one element returned or you will need $('.myimage:eq(0)').width()
}
```

You would just use it like this:

```
if (currentWidth()>400) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for :) I was only hoping that it could be attached to a variable but it turns out that it's not possible.